# What is the best practice on fetching data after a post request in Node?

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I have a form in Node where i create a user.
When the form is submitted i trigger a post request which adds the user to the database.

How do i fetch the data in the quickest and most efficient way to get a new list of users to display on the user list?

Should i add a GET request in the submitHandler right after i submitted the POST request?

```
function Form({}: User) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useContext(UserContext);

  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>({
    _id: Math.random().toString(),
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
  });

  const handleSubmit = async (e: MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>, user: User) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstname: user.firstname,
        lastname: user.lastname,
      }),
    };

    const response = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:3030/api/user",
      requestOptions
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
      throw new Error(message);
    }

    setUser({
      _id: "",
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
    });
  };
```

And the form:

```
<FormWrapper>
        <form action="">
          <label htmlFor="">Firstname:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name=""
            id=""
            value={user.firstname}
            onChange={(e) => setUser({ ...user, firstname: e.target.value })}
          />
          <label htmlFor="">Lastname:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name=""
            id=""
            value={user.lastname}
            onChange={(e) => setUser({ ...user, lastname: e.target.value })}
          />
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Submit"
            onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e, user)}
          />
        </form>
      </FormWrapper>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is common practice to return a new user as a response to a **POST** request.
For example:

```
// creating new user 
const newUser = await fetch('...') 
// the response might look like: { id: 1, userName: '...', etc.}
```

In this case, there is no need to perform an additional **GET** request. If this cannot be done, then you will have to request updated data.

As for the UI, there are two options: *optimistic* or *pessimistic* update. In the first case, you update the UI immediately and wait for a response. In case of failure, the UI is rolled back to the previous state (e.g., deleting a new user and showing an error message). In case of a pessimistic update, you wait for a response and only then update the UI.
Choose what is more suitable in your situation.

Comment: So i add the user as an optimistic update and then when do i refetch the users?